# Is assigning a result value of a method faster than calling that method again?

Tags: c#

Just out of curiosity which of these would be faster and better in terms of performance?

Some really basic code:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("FOO");
list.Add("BAR");
```

1)

```
//Calling count twice in the if statement
if(list.Count() > 0 || list.Count() < 3)
{
    Console.WriteLine("There are two items");
}
```

2)

```
//Assigning count return result to a variable
var listCount = list.Count();
if(listCount > 0 || listCount < 3)
{
   Console.WriteLine("There are two items");
}
```

Comment: What do you think? Have you tried putting the code above l00,000 times (looped) and see which one runs faster?

Comment: Does it matter @Tarec?

Comment: While in this case the semantics are the same, there may be other reasons which would dictate whether you should call the method, or assign values.

Comment: Well I'm not asking which `count` method is faster @Tarec

Comment: @Tarec Please make me understand: Why do you think a Property or a Method makes any difference for the question? If you compile it a Property in such a case will also just be a method call.

Comment: @Offler it's not about whether he calls a method or not, it's about what that method does. What's the point of counting items ammount and storing it in a variable, if it's already there? How can you justify such a meaningless micro-optimization while ignoring few times bigger performance impact of this pointless approach at the same time? Check my answer.

Comment: @Tarec If you can read then take notice of the first four words of the opening line of the question "Just out of curiosity". So relax, don't be that guy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is "it depends". I'm sure there are scenarios in which calling a method twice is faster, but I would say the overwhelming majority of the time, it is faster to assign the return value to a variable, and simply reference that variable.

If you know using a method (or property, since those are just a type of method) is expensive, then you should definitely store the result.

My rule of thumb is that if I use a return value more than once, I'll store it in a variable. The only time I wouldn't do that is if you know that the return value is likely to change between method calls.

But in your example of accessing `Count` or `Count()`, the latter is fast for the `List<>` type (but can be expensive for other types), the performance improvement you get over storing it to a variable vs calling it twice is negligible, so I would do whatever makes you happy.

Comment: `he latter is fast for the List<> type` - because the extension method actually attempts a cast to `ICollection<T>`. If that succeeds, then it just returns the collections `Count` property. So the overhead is in the method call and attempted cast (just a bit of extra info).

Answer (score 1):

These are results I've got after 100 000 000 iterations:

00:00:01.9444910 s for double calling `Count()` method

00:00:01.9531469 s for calling `Count()` once and storing it in a variable

00:00:00.3298595 s for checking against `Count` property.

Comment: Is this run based on `Count` vs `Count()` or method call vs variable assigment

Comment: Yes, double call vs. variable assignment.